# Traps and tricks for White in the 4.Bf4 variation vs the Grunfeld

Tags: opening, grunfeld-defense

I read in a book (I no longer remember what book) that there are a few traps for White in the `1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 g6 3.Nc3 d5 4.Bf4` variation vs the Grunfeld, and that the line is somehow popular among GMs, Black has no easy equality, etc. etc. Is anyone aware of what a few of these tricks / traps for White might be?

For example please notice GM Kavalek's comments after Bf4 in this article:

https://www.huffingtonpost.com/lubomir-kavalek/the-most-treacherous-defe_b_991426.html

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BX9Ax29jZ1k is video 1 of 4 explaining this system.  Mike Virgo has the links to the rest of the series.
One of the comments is:  "It is a good video, however, Roman makes one mistake. at 15:45, he forgot to place pawn on h3 back to h2.﻿"  Many minor errors show in most chess videos, so ensure you understand the moves.

Answer (score -2):

There are always tricks and traps, in every possible chess opening, not just the Gruenfeld.
It has to be noted, though, that 4.cd5 Nd5 5.e4 is much stronger than Bf4, white has tremendous performance with that at the highest level, namely the TCEC top engine chess competition.

From what one might infer the Gruenfeld is an altogether dubious opening with perfect play(not so many KID lines).
Of course, if you miss the best continuations, the Gruenfeld might also score well for black.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the computer play I'll have to check that out. I have heard humans were having difficulty with bf4 tho